# short script to read and create matching directories

Tags: scripting, directory

I need to do a `z:\music\: dir *flac*`  to get a listing of directories... (they are named Artist - Album [flac])

and from that list of directors, create new matching directories, but replace the [flac] part with [mp3]

I can do this from linux, or windows. Either is available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this

```
#!/bin/bash
find /mount/point/of/z -type d -name '*flac*' | while read dir
do
   newdir=`echo $dir | sed -e 's/\[flac\]/\[mp3\]/'`
   mkdir -p "$newdir"
done
```

Comment: If I enter "find /mount/point/of/z -type d -name '*flac*' | while read dir" I just get the carat >

Comment: But the script worked beautifully. If you cared to explain what's up with the first line I'd really appreciate it...

Comment: first find as you suggest with 'flac' wont find anything as that would be looking for exactly directories named 'flac' not ones containing flac, thats why i wrote '*flac*' ... basically script finds all dirs that contain flac, and substitutes flac string for mp3 string with the sed command, then after it creates directory that contains switched strings flac -> mp3